# Can I validate functions with Clojure spec?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Can I use the Clojure spec system to define function signatures and verify if functions satisfy them?

Here are some examples I've tried without success

```clj
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args string? :ret string?) identity) ;; false

(def nope identity)
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args string? :ret string?) nope) ;; false

(s/conform (s/fspec :args string? :ret string?) identity) ;; invalid

(defn strmap [s] {:pre [(s/valid? string? s)] :post [(s/valid? string? %)]} s)
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args string? :ret string?) strmap) ;; false

(s/fdef strmap :args string? :ret string?)
(s/valid? strmap strmap) ;; true

(s/def ::str-pred (s/fspec :args string? :ret boolean?))
(s/valid ::str-pred (fn [s] true)) ;; false
```

I know about `fdef`, but I'd like something I can compose. For example, creating a map of related function signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out spec does handle functions, but it expects the arguments to be a tuple.

```clj
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args (s/cat :arg1 string?) :ret string?) identity) ;; true!
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args (s/cat :arg1 string?) :ret string?) (fn [x] (str x "hi there"))) ;; true
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args (s/cat :arg1 string?) :ret string?) (fn [x] x)) ;; true

(s/valid? (s/fspec :args (s/cat :arg1 string?) :ret string?) (fn [x] 42)) ;; false
```

There does appear to be some issues with the anonymous function literal. I'm probably misunderstanding something about the macro expansion.

```clj
(s/valid? (s/fspec :args (s/cat :arg1 string?) :ret string?) #(%)) ;; false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the `:args` and `:ret` spec of a function using `s/get-spec` and then validate:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])
nil
user=> (defn strmap [s] s)
#'user/strmap
user=> (s/fdef strmap :args string? :ret string?)
user/strmap
user=> (s/valid? (:args (s/get-spec `strmap)) "foo")
true
user=> (s/valid? (:args (s/get-spec `strmap)) :bar)
false
```

I am using this in [re-find.web](https://borkdude.github.io/re-find.web/).

Comment: Hmm. I'll need to play with this. I think what I want is to compare `(s/get-spec \`strmap)` against some `s/fspec`.

Comment: Initial investigations are not looking promising. `(= (:args (s/get-spec \`strmap)) (s/spec string?))` returns false

Comment: It's worth noting that `(= (s/spec string?) (s/spec string?))` is true but `(s/def ::hi string?) (= (s/get-spec ::hi) (s/spec string?))` is false. `(def hi (s/spec string?)) (= hi (s/spec string?))` is also false. I think I'm not understanding spec equality

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to `clojure.spec`, [`malli`](https://github.com/metosin/malli) is a data-driven schema library that has [support for function schemas](https://github.com/metosin/malli#function-schemas)

Comment: I would prefer not to migrate my current spec. An official library like spec is also the best bet for tooling integration.